# Burmese Unicode font not displaying properly in browser

Tags: unicode, visual-studio-code, encoding, fonts

I'm creating a website with Burmese font in it. In my code editor, I have this [image]

The left side text that's more clear is what i typed in, the right side is what I've copy and pasted from a website. But when I try to see it in browser, I see this instead[image]

The right side which displays properly on my code editor isn't displaying properly on the browser, however on the left side is. This applies to any Burmese text. The text that I input with my keyboard doesn't display properly but the text that I paste does.

I do have `<meta charset="UTF-8"/>` declared in my `<head>`

I'm currently using VS Code as my code editor and Myanmar 3 as my keyboard source. I know my Myanmar input works because I can type it and it shows properly on other sites such as facebook or twitter but it's just not encoding properly on the browser.

Sample code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>More text မြန်မာပြည် ျမန္မာျပည္ </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you show the actual [mcve] here? E.g. an HTML document that only has as much in the `<head>` as necessary (meta, font-face links, etc), and a `<body>` with a single `<p>` with your text in it, and the appropriate CSS class set so that it uses the correct font?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans added! When I paste back the sample code block, it seems like VS Code has switched the order that it was copied (i.e. the proper version onto the left and the weird version onto the right). Is it a VS Code encoding issue?

Comment: Almost certainly, yes. Can you paste some proper burmese text (or just write it)? This is also usually how you test encoding issues: using something like jsbin or glitch to see if, when you write the text you know you need, things work. If so, it's almost certainly your tooling causing problems.

Comment: Hmm yeah i just tested by typing some more vs pasting. Seems like current work around will be type somewhere else and then paste it in. I've tried to change VS Code's default encoding to from like UTF-8 to like UTF-16 but doesnt' work either. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: VS Code should be writing almost all its files as UTF-8, certainly not UTF-16. It sounds like just your copy-paste went wrong, though: if you type the text over in VS Code, does it look and render just fine?

Comment: When I type in VS Code it looks fine but it doesn't look fine in browser (as shown in the original screenshots)

Comment: This might actually be worth asking over on https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues, too, because it sounds like there might be a bug in VS Code that the authors should be aware of.

Comment: Got it. Thank you!